# DataGridView Edit Column Names

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Is there any way to edit column names in a DataGridView?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think there is a way to do it without writing custom code.
I'd implement a ColumnHeaderDoubleClick event handler, and create a TextBox control right on top of the column header.

Answer (score 33):

You can also change the column name by using:

```
myDataGrid.Columns[0].HeaderText = "My Header"
```

but the `myDataGrid` will need to have been bound to a `DataSource`.

Answer (score 11):

You can edit the header directly:

```
dataGridView1.Columns[0].HeaderCell.Value = "Created";
dataGridView1.Columns[1].HeaderCell.Value = "Name";
```

And so on for as many columns you have.

Answer (score 8):

@Dested if you are populating DataGrid from DataReader, you can change the name of columns in your query

for example

```
select ID as "Customer ID", CstNm as "First Name", CstLstNm as "Last Name"
from Customers
```

this way in your data grid you will see Customer ID instead of ID and so forth.

Answer (score 2):

I guess what you want is to edit the HeaderText property of the column:

```
myDataGrid.TableStyles[0].GridColumnStyles[0].HeaderText = "My Header"
```

**Source**: http://forums.microsoft.com/MSDN/ShowPost.aspx?PostID=186908&SiteID=1

Answer (score 2):

You can also edit directly without knowing anything as posted above
:

```
protected void gvCSMeasureCompare_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
        e.Row.Cells[0].Text = "New Header for Column 1";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
myDataGrid.Columns[0].HeaderText = "My Header"
myDataGrid.Bind() ;
```