# When you bind list<> to datagrid - how to change column names?

Tags: c#, data-binding, datagridview

I have a code:

```
VideoChannel[] channels = GetVideoChannels();

dataGridView1.DataSource = channels;
dataGridView1.Refresh();
```

VideoChannel is a class with many properties. This code works OK, but I want to change column names. By default, column name = property name of VideoChannel. Is there some attribute that I can mark a property of VideoChannel so column name != property name ?

Answer (score 12):

You may want to try [`DisplayName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.displaynameattribute%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) Attribute. Decorate your class property with it.

```
 public class SomeItem
    {
        [DisplayName("SomeItem")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: So simple, yet so useful.

Answer (score 1):

You can change column name in design mode where you create column and set it's properties.
Or you can try

```
DataGridName.Colimns[0].HeaderText = "Your Header0";
DataGridName.Colimns[1].HeaderText = "Your Header1";
.
.
.
DataGridName.Colimns[N].HeaderText = "Your HeaderN";
```

But the better way is to do this in design mode.

Comment: I know how to set column name programmatically, I asked about if I can set it automatically using some attributes in binding class.

Comment: Yes you can do that. oops by the way which one r u using wpf or winforms .? 
If you r using wpf then u can set bind the header text of datagrid column with 1 of the property of VideoChannel class

Comment: WinForms.
That solution doesn't fit me. I don't want to set header text manually - i want it will be automatically using attributes of my custom structure fields.

Answer (score 0):

Will this help you

`dataGridView1.TableStyles[0].GridColumnStyles[0].HeaderText = "SomeDifferentColumnName"`

or

`dataGridView1.Columns[0].HeaderText = "SomeDifferentColumnName"`

Source: [DataGridView Edit Column Names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/125719/datagridview-edit-column-names)

Source in turn: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/winformsdatacontrols/thread/8b9b07d4-06fc-4c12-9509-0c19ca04e003/

Comment: In that option, I must manually assign header text to columns. I don't like this solution. Maybe, there is some attribute that I can use with videochannel properties ?