# iterate datagridview columns and change column header

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

How to rename the columns' headers of datagridview dynamically?

until now I used this code:

```
dataGridView1.Columns[0].HeaderText = "my_title";
```

the problem is that Columns[0] might change with time..

How can I iterate on all the Columns Headers and do something like

```
if (Column.HeaderText=="customer_id") {Column.HeaderText="my_title"} ?
```

Comment: check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/125719/datagridview-edit-column-names

Comment: actually I saw that post before asking, but I couldn't understand from it what is the conclusion? that it's not possible to implement?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just use a foreach to iterate over all columns:

```
foreach(DataGridViewColumn column in dataGridView1.Columns)
{
    if (column.HeaderText=="customer_id") { column.HeaderText="my_title" }
}
```

This of course would only change the header text for the one column.
If you want to set custom header text for multiple columns you could use a `switch` instead of the `if`.

Comment: it doesn't compile? I get an error 'object' does not contain a definition for 'HeaderText'..

Comment: Yes, my mistake. Can't use `var` in the foreach. It now compiles and works as expected.

Comment: Thank you! this works. How could I 'guess' that I should write "DataGridViewColumn" in the foreach? the intellisense shows that dataGridView1.Columns returns "DataGridViewColumnCollection"?

Comment: The use of the indexer `dataGridView.Columns[0]` tells you the object type you get when enumerating.

Comment: @BornToCode: It's also always a good startingpoint to look at the [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumncollection%28v=vs.90%29) if you are not sure about what type is used etc. :)

Answer (score -1):

```
foreach (DataGridViewColumn column in dataGridView1.Columns)
{
    if (column.HeaderText == "customer_id")
    {
        column.HeaderText = "my_title"
    }
}
```